# How to get image coordinates in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, drawing, signature, coordinate-transformation

I have to implement a signature functionality in my iPad app. I convert the signature into image and after that I want to get coordinates of that image. How could I do it plz help me.

Note: I am not talking about latitude and longitude. I am talking about pixels coordinates

Comment: how is the design of the interface? is the user signing into an `UIImageView` or into a `UIView`? which coordinates are you interest on, respect the container view or *globals* coordinates?

Comment: User is drawing on a UIView

Comment: ok, and wich coordinates are you interest on?

Comment: i want coordinated of pixels

Comment: do you want to crop the image to the area where the user sign?

Comment: no i just have to save coordinates of sign and want to send it on server side DB

Comment: The coordinates of each pixel?, sorry but I still don't know what you need

Comment: Yes i want to get x and y axis of each pixel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIViewController` is a subclass of `UIResponder`, so you can implement the methods `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` to detect "signing movements".

For example using the method `-touchesMoved:withEvent:`

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(currentPosition));
}
```

For more info check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder) of the `UIResponder` class